# Stored procedures in SSIS Packages

Tags: ssis

We are doing a huge Data Migration Project using SSIS packages. We were insisted on not using stored procedures in SSIS packages. Can you please suggest whether we should be using stored procedures in SSIS packages or not? What are the advantages of using stored procedures?

Comment: Surely you should ask the people who told you not to use stored procedures why they thought that was a bad idea.

Comment: Maybe this is a reason: if You are using stored procedures to migrate between two distinct servers, then You have to use linked (federated) servers and that might be bad idea, probably SSIS is better solution because it independently reads data from source and writes to destination. Also, there might be some transformations that are better to be done in ssis. As usual, it depends, and if this answer is not what You are looking for, then ask those who told You not to use stored procedures in the first place :)

Comment: I forgot to comment the second question: there is no reason not to use  stored procedures from ssis, it just depends on your needs, environment and limitations. It is ok to call sp from ssis, but if all you do from ssis is calling stored procedures, then you don't need ssis. ssis main purpose is to read data from source, do the transformations in memory and write to destination.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1773453/advantages-of-using-ssis-packages-over-stored-procedures
See this question thread

Comment: A stored procedure is a bunch of SQL code saved in a database. So you can just put that code inside a bunch of Execute SQL statements instead of the database if you like. Your sp directive smells like some high-falutin architect wanting things done their way rather than actually being any reason. In my ETL work I use many stored procedures because the equivalent SSIS functionality is inferior (i.e. the SCD component)

Answer (score 1):

**It is correct that merge statements can easily be used in SSIS** and your directive to encapsulate everything in SSIS is not necessary, as SQL processing aggregations faster than SSIS, for example. Further, if you are not deploying to SSISDB or have proper logging wrappers or email alerts, then troubleshooting your ETL is going to be more difficult via the SQL agent than otherwise as the errors are frequently more cryptic - thus the SSISDB and its reports in 2012. [SSIS can be extremely powerful](http://www.technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537533(v=sql.100).aspx), however.

Here is a [**fairly blatant benchmark**](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/chriss-sql-blog/2012/07/03/ssis-scd-vs-merge-statement-performance-comparison/) that will tell you **never to use the out of the box SCD ever in SSIS**. Taskfactory however does have a nice deployable which does basically merges behind the scene.

[SSIS has more powerful functions than Stored Procedures.](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/1c6ebe87-8f70-4bfb-9c76-40e6c19c605d/stored-procedures-vs-ssis-packages-in-defining-business-logic) 
However you can easily use Execute T-SQL Statement tasks in SSIS for existing tasks, and then build out from there.

- SSIS is superior at the vast majority of ETL

Below Via Microsoft

1. Microsoft Integration Services is a platform for building enterprise-level data integration and data transformations solutions. You use Integration Services to solve complex business problems by copying or downloading files, defining business logic, sending e-mail messages in response to events, updating data warehouses, cleaning and mining data, and managing SQL Server objects and data. The packages can work alone or in concert with other packages to address complex business needs. Integration Services can extract and transform data from a wide variety of sources such as XML data files, flat files, and relational data sources, and then load the data into one or more destinations.

Integration Services includes a rich set of built-in tasks and transformations; tools for constructing packages; and the Integration Services service for running and managing packages. You can use the graphical Integration Services tools to create solutions without writing a single line of code; or you can program the extensive Integration Services object model to create packages programmatically and code custom tasks and other package objects.

2. A stored procedure in SQL Server is a group of one or more Transact-SQL statements or a reference to a Microsoft .NET Framework common runtime language (CLR) method. They can be called from within SSIS just the same as the unencapsulated SQL statement. For more information about it, please see: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190782(v=sql.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190782%28v=sql.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Dude you just regurgitated a bunch of pages. I don't think this is very useful

Comment: This is obvious, I linked it and pasted it directly. This answer was marked as the answer on the Microsoft forums by a MSFT partner. If you find it unhelpful, great - you clearly cannot be helped where others found it then.

Comment: Apologies - I didn't mean to be rude. I can see from your other comments that you do know what you're talking about. The thing is that MS forum answer was _in turn_ regurgitated from here:  https://books.google.com.au/books?id=rcFlCQAAQBAJ&pg=PT2310&lpg=PT2310&dq=You+use+Integration+Services+to+solve+complex+business+problems&source=bl&ots=Krmu1QXzvR&sig=prJ8P3b9LuL19qdXDqrykX9J0Zw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiphczrnOzLAhXC3KYKHdO-BucQ6AEIJzAC#v=onepage&q=You%20use%20Integration%20Services%20to%20solve%20complex%20business%20problems&f=false.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid Your link just Inceptioned me. I am a walking hyperlink robot and proud of it, to be honest.

Comment: It's true - most answers are already online you just have to find them.

Comment: Please consider removing the downvote @Nick.McDermaid