# Periodic table update from another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis

In this example, I have two tables in my DB.  Table A receives data via SSIS from an external DB once a day.  This information then needs to update records on Table B.  The tables are joined by a two part primary key.

```
Table A
Mref
Rref
HD_Status
SL_Status
JB_Status

Table B
MrefIn
RrefIn
HD Status
SL Status
JB Status
```

The keys link by `Mref = mrefIn & Rref = RrefIn`.

The update script I've written is

```
UPDATE dbo.Table A
set     HD_Status = dbo.Table B.HD Status,
        SL_Status = dbo.Table B.SL Status,
        JB_Status = dbo.Table B.JB Status
from dbo.Table B
where dbo.Table A.Mref = dbo.Table B.MrefIn AND 
dbo.Table A.Rref = dbo.Table B.RrefIn
```

My question is: what is the best way to run this script, once a morning at 6am?  I'm thinking SSIS but not exactly sure if this is the best practice.  There should be no more than 1000 records to update.

Any replies are greatly appreciated!

Steve

Comment: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/c6044f61-ec35-4771-b04c-9d3cfbff0c5a/ssis-jobs-vs-sql-server-job-agent?forum=sqlintegrationservices  A job calling a t-SQL procedure within a database makes the most sense.  SSIS is typically used for outside in or inside out (one database to another)  supported http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1773453/advantages-of-using-ssis-packages-over-stored-procedures in comment

Comment: I agree.  A scheduled job...with a schedule that makes the most sense for you.  "Before business hours" is a fairly common approach.

Answer (score 0):

A scheduled Stored Procedure was the way to go.

Thanks.