# Run A Query in intervals [Hourly-Based]

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, webforms

I have a small website that read stock-information from a Soap-API.

The Case I have here is that I need to have a chart to show the change over the price in a period of time including daily monthly.. etc

In the daily manner: I need to read the data from an API and store it to a Table with hourly intervals  at the background of the application.

How to run that with asp.net web-form website?

Comment: Generally the web application wouldn't do this.  You'd have something like a Windows Service or scheduled Console Application to run at regular intervals.

Comment: @David May you please provide a good example about it ? thanks

Comment: Looks like a good for the Agent to do.

Comment: @hejazi: An example about how to make a Console Application?  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/get-started/csharp/tutorial-console?view=vs-2019  A Windows Service?  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/windows-services/walkthrough-creating-a-windows-service-application-in-the-component-designer

Comment: Instead of hitting web or window then again hitting databse to update.uou can hit webservice directly from sql server and update, like SSIS or Proc.

Comment: @KumarHarsh  this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/1777672/12137978 gives a clue where to use SSIS and SP. so In my case i think it really okay to go with SP. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a procedure that updates the destination table and this procedure runs following a call from your application that runs automatically on a time interval. The procedure call can be made from a web api, windows service, console application ... etc.

**In SQL Server : Create Procedure**

```
USE DatabaseName
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.UpdateChartTable ( @Parma1 varchar(50), @Param2 varchar(50))
AS 
.................
.................
GO
```

**In the application,call automatically the procedure, for example from a thread.**

**Declaration of the thread**

```
myThread = new Thread(() => ThreaReadingRefreshUserInterface());
myThread.Start();
```

**The Update Function which runs every 5 seconds**

```
private void ThreaReadingRefreshUserInterface()
{
  try
   {
     SqlConnection MyConnection = new SqlConnection(MyConnectionString);
     SqlCommand MyCommand = new SqlCommand("UpdateChartTable", MyConnection);
     MyCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
     MyCommand.Parameters.Add("@Parma1", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = "Parma1";
     MyCommand.Parameters.Add("@Param2", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = "Param2";
     sqlConnection.Open();
     return MyCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
     sqlConnection.Close();
  }
  catch (SqlException ex)
  {

  }
  TimeSpan tms;
  tms = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 5);
  Thread.Sleep(tms);
  ThreaReadingRefreshUserInterface();
}
```

Cordially

Comment: Just to be mentioned here, you can also use "Timer" instead of Thread to do the job.